# Is it ok to say "makes areas sharpen"

Tags: word-usage

The context is explaining how Photoshop tool "Sharpen Tool" works.

> This tool makes areas sharpen

Is it ok to say that? I mean to use `sharpen` there?

Comment: Check out (on meta): [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can sharpen an image, or a border, but I would be reluctant to say "sharpen an area". Also "sharpen" here is a transitive verb form, meaning "to make sharper" so I would never say "make X  sharpen". I would say either "sharpen X" or "make X sharp**er**"

Recall that the original meaning of "sharpen" is what one does to a knife, to give it a sharp edge, and its use in imaging is a derived use, even a metaphor.

"To make areas sharpen" would be to somehow  make the areas sharpen something else. It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I think "sharpen an area" probably means "sharpen a [selected] area [of an image]." While it may sound awkward out of context, I don't know if it would really be all that problematic in a context such as Photoshop documentation.

Comment: @J.R.  I think you are correct on the intended meaning, and in context it would probably be understood, but if I read tht in such a manual, I would say "another manual translated from an oriental language by Google Translate". In short, I would make me stare and think "poor writing".. I advise learners not to use that form.

Comment: @DavidSiegel... do you mean "make areas sharper" is incorrect?

Comment: @DavidS - I'm having a little trouble seeing why _sharpen X_ is okay, but _sharpen a selected area of an image_ is "poor writing". _X_ cannot be a selected area of an image?